# Modify Twilio statusCallback during live call

Tags: node.js, callback, twilio

I am trying to update a statusCallback during a live call.  When I set the statusCallback statically in the console the callback triggers and everything functions as expected.

When I try to update the callback during a live call, the callback seems to be ignored.  Am I supposed to be able to change the statusCallback during a live call?  Am I missing something obvious?

Code snippet:

```
    var callsid = A_VALID_SID_OBTAINED_PROGRAMATICALLY;
    var statuscallback = A_VALID_URL_WHICH_WORKS_WHEN_DEFINED_STATICALLY_IN_CONTROLPANEL;
    
    var client = require('twilio')(MYACCOUNT,MYSID);
    
    client.calls(callsid).update({
       statusCallback: statuscallback
    })
    .then(call => {
       callback(null,"SUCCESS");
    });
```

Comment: Why are you trying to update the statusCallback during a call?

Comment: @Alan on completion of the call, and only on the completion of the call I update a database.  The call is inbound so the dial-verb doesnt seem to apply.  Depending on the route that triggers the inbound call, I need to utilize discrete callbacks.

Comment: You can set the `Call Status Changes` on a Twilio number which will fire once the call is completed. This is used for inbound calls.

Comment: @Alan, this works as expected when I set it statically in the control panel.  I'm looking for a method to set this dynamically from the function that the phone number utilizes (webhook, twilio function, twiml bin, etc).  I can't seem to find documentation or code examples that illustrate this.

Comment: You can set this via API but it can't be set once the call is established, here is documentation for the API - https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource (the update example)

Comment: @Alan, thank you.  I think I need to change my approach, this answers a number of questions!